# Getting the chosen color from a color well programatically

Tags: objective-c

I have built a color well using objective c and cocoa but I am having trouble getting the color out using takeColorFrom:.  My example would not be useful because I am writing all this in lisp with an objective c bridge.  Could someone link me to an example of how to do this in objective C and I can easily translate from that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'takeColorFrom:' is to set the color of your well from an external object.  You probably want the 'color' method, which returns the color of your NSColorWell object.

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColorWell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSColorWell/takeColorFrom:):

---

**color**
Returns the color of the receiver.

```
- (NSColor *)color
```

**Return Value**
The color of the receiver.

---

**takeColorFrom:**
Changes the color of the receiver to that of the specified object.

```
- (void)takeColorFrom:(id)sender
```

**Parameters**
*sender*
The object from which to take the new color.